# Освобождается ли память, выделенная под переменную ссылочного типа, которая объявлена внутри метода?

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Допустим, имеется метод внутри класса:

```
public ICollection<Entity> GetData()
{
    ICollection<Entity> rezult;
    var tempCollection = context.Get<Entity>();
    //doing some stuff;
    return rezult;
}
```

Как ни крути, мне в коде нужна эта временная переменная. Вопрос состоит в том, нужно ли "занулять" эту переменную (`tempCollection = null;`), чтобы **GC** при сборке мусора понял, что она уже не нужна, или же это и так будет понятно, посколько она объявлена внутри метода?

Comment: С C# вам не нужно думать об освобождении памяти (практически) никогда. Как только память вам перестанет быть нужна, она становится доступна сборщику мусора. НО: переменная — это вовсе не память! Переменная — это место, куда может быть положена ссылка на выделенную память. Память под переменную выделяет компилятор, и он вообще может переместить её в регистр, или в стек, или перемещать между этими местами, или дублировать, или вообще не выделять, как ему угодно. Вы никак не можете повлиять на память для _переменных_ (и не должны пытаться, компилятор делает это лучше).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При завершении метода все его локальные переменные пропадают (если только не были захвачены замыканием). Отдельно занулять их не нужно.

Comment: А иногда и до завершения метода они пропадают :)

Answer (score 7):

Объект, на который ссылается `tempCollection`, превращается в мусор сразу же после последнего упоминания `tempCollection` в теле метода - т.е. иногда задолго до того, как метод вернет управление.

GC собирает объекты после того, как они станут недостижимыми - т.е. после того, как их, прямо или косвенно, нельзя будет увидеть из т.н. корней - статических полей, локальных переменных и еще пары специфических мест. Как только объект становится недостижим - GC может его спокойно убить.

Предположим что ваш метод выгдядит вот так:

```
public ICollection<Entity> GetData()
{
    ICollection<Entity> rezult;
    var tempCollection = context.Get<Entity>();
    // doing some stuff 

    // последнее упоминание tempCollection в методе:
    var something = tempCollection.SomeProp; 

    // doing some more stuff;
    return rezult;
}
```

Локальная переменная `tempCollection` упоминается только в верхней половине метода. Ниже этой строчки код никак не может получить доступ к ее содержимому. Так что GC вполне справедливо не считает ее корнем в нижней половине метода.

Учитывая это, добавление дополнительного упоминания `tempCollection` в коде (пусть даже и в виде `tempCollection = null`) не сократит, а наоборот, чуть-чуть продлит время его жизни.

---

Стоит отметить, что при сборке в Debug, в отличии от Release, JIT заботится о вашем удобстве, и продлевает область жизни `tempCollection` до конца области видимости (т.е. до конца метода). Делает он это исключительно из соображений удобства при отладке - чтобы вы могли просмотреть значение `tempCollection` даже на последней строчке метода.